# Can we get files from a non Default branch?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a build pipeline that I want to trigger when the workspace_publish branch has changes to it, which is fine and this is currently working using these settings:

[image]

However, I want the Agent to extract the SQL Scripts (on the second step) from a different branch in the "Synapse Reporting" repository, NOT the workspace_publish branch.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is fairly simple. You simply add another artifact to your pipeline that points to the source control branch you are interested in:

[image]

You then have 2 artifacts that are copied over and can be accessed during your release process.